# Ticking a checkbox with PHP to put in Wordpress function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I recently discovered a method of changing Wordpress preferences if you do something silly that makes the wp-admin not load.  I found that inserting things into the `function.php` file found in the theme and using the `update_option` command allowed me to change the settings i needed to get be working again.

This got me thinking, i have the need to install the same theme with the same settings.  This is a pain as i have to define all the settings each time.  Instead i am trying to make a functions.php file that will set all the settings to how i like them.

I am able to update settings that require you to type a string into a field

```
//this will change the siteurl setting to www.mysite.com
update_option ('siteurl','www.mysite.com');
```

My issue is that i need to be able to do the same thing for checkboxes, drop down menus and for radio buttons.  After a long night or searching the internet for examples i had given up until i found this site.

Any help would be appreciated, i have minimal programming experience but i do understand the concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in theory `update_option('checkboxname',true);` or `update_option('checkboxname','on');`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: that's what i thought, well more accurately, i thought i could put in "1" as they have a value field. If i look at the source of the page, every checkbox has the following code 'value="1"' regardless if the checkbox is ticked or not,  the ticked checkboxes have the following code 'value="1" checked="checked"' This completely confused me.

Comment: Can you post some more code around where your editing? If you cannot get your answers here try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note: i have got checkboxes to work with `update_option('checkboxname',true);` but i don't know how to do radio buttons or drop down menues

Comment: Great! For the dropdown you will need to specify the value attribute of the desired option `<option value="1">Setting One</option>` will be '1' - `update_option('dropdownname',1);`

Comment: @cropla - thanks so much for your assistance, i will try that when i get home.  The one that is getting me stuck though is the multi selection box, i want to select various options by their value names. I have also noticed that this element has two square brackets after its name which non of the other elements (checkbox etc) had.  eg. `Select name=clockcountry_banlist[]"......` i am not sure if this has any effect on the syntax needed.

Comment: i have resolved the issue with the multi selection box. The code is without the square brackets and looks like this. `update_option ('blockcountry_banlist',array(AE, EU, AU)); `